# Reading input separated by space

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I wanted to first take an integer N followed by N lines where each line has two coordinates x and y. (separated by space). I tried doing it but it is giving `NullPointerException`.

```
class solution{

class Point{
int x;
int y;
} 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
int N;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
N=Integer.parseInt(in.next());
Point[] P = new Point[N];
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
String[] s1 = inp.readLine().split(" ");
P[i].x=Integer.parseInt(s1[0]);
P[i].y=Integer.parseInt(s1[1]);
} 
}
```

example of input:

```
4
2 4
5 7
8 9
1 0
```

Comment: Why are you using `Scanner` and `BufferedReader` both? Use either of them.

Comment: Ok, Can you tell us in which line you get NullPointerException?

Comment: @RohitJain JUST TO PRACTICE..And please its not any homework

Comment: @Ajeesh P[i].x=Integer.parseInt(s1[0]); in this line

Comment: P[i] is null, because you have never initialized it. Thus P[i].x throws the NPE. Creating the array does not fill its fields automagically.

Comment: @user119249 Yeah it's good to practice. But you shouldn't be reading simultaneously using two readers from the same stream. At least not unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @sheltem what are you saying? i dont get u.

Comment: @RohitJain ok.Its not matter of concern here i think.I can change it

Comment: Point[] P = new Point[N] creates an array of *empty fields* (nulls), not instances of Point. Before you can access a value x or y from a Point, you have to create that Point. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: @sheltem what should i do here according to u?

Comment: Add a line 'P[i] = new Point();' (without the '') before you try to assign values to P[i].x or P[i].y. That won't work, since you are using an inner class and would then need an enclosing instance of that class. So remove your own version of Point and just import java.awt.Point for it (which already does what you are trying to do with your own inner class).

Comment: Check what value you get by using the below code, String val=inp.readLine(); System.out.println("Value: "+val); String[] s1 = inp.readLine().split(" ");

Answer (score 1):

In your program exception occurs at `P[i].x=Integer.parseInt(s1[0]);`

Try this .....

```
public class solution{

    Set<Point> s=new LinkedHashSet<>();
    class Point{
    int x;
    int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    solution s=new solution();
    s.setValues();
    s.printValues();
    }

    private void setValues() {
    int N;
    System.out.println("Enter Limit:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    N=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter "+N+" numbers with space:");
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    String[] s1 = in.nextLine().split(" ");
    s.add(new Point(Integer.parseInt(s1[0]),Integer.parseInt(s1[1])));
    } 
    }

    private void printValues() {
        System.out.println("Enter numbers are:");
        for (Iterator<Point> it = s.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Point s = it.next();
            System.out.println("x="+s.getX()+"  and y="+s.getY());
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Enter Limit:
4
Enter 4 numbers with space:
4 8
1 9
7 8
2 3
Enter numbers are:
x=4  and y=8
x=1  and y=9
x=7  and y=8
x=2  and y=3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Solution {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        int size;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        size = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        Point[] points = new Point[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            String[] pointInput = in.nextLine().split(" ");
            points[i] = new Point();
            points[i].x = Integer.parseInt(pointInput[0]);
            points[i].y = Integer.parseInt(pointInput[1]);
        }
        in.close();
        for (Point point : points) {
            System.out.println("This is a point: " + point.x + ", " + point.y);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a working example of what you say you want to do. Judging from your question and the following comments I would strongly advise you to work through a few basic tutorials on Java before continuing on with this. Because unless you actually understand what happens where, giving you this answer will have done nothing useful in the end.